# How do I preserve whitespace in a Maven plugin configuration?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

I have a plugin configuration parameter named `suffix`.  I would like the user to be able to specify a newline (a literal character produced by pressing the `Return` key, not some escaped variant, although I'll get to that) as the value for that parameter.

At the same time, the parameter has a `default-value` setting.  I would like to continue to use that.

How do I specify, in my plugin's configuration stanza, that the `suffix` parameter should take a newline?

I've tried this:

```
<suffix><![CDATA[
]]></suffix>
```

...and this:

```
<suffix>${line.separator}</suffix>
```

...(that one actually substitutes the right character in but XML parsing stomps on it) and this:

```
<suffix><[!CDATA[${line.separator}]]></suffix>
```

...and this:

```
<suffix>&x0d;</suffix>
```

...and this:

```
<suffix xml:space="preserve">
</suffix>
```

...all to no avail.  Specifically, I see the default value of the parameter instead.

**Edit**: Interestingly, the whitespace is eaten long before Maven's internals ever get a chance to work on the value.  `mvn help:effective-pom` will show that the whitespace has been removed.  Leading, trailing and "only" whitespace content is removed early on in the parsing stage.

This seems to me most likely to be a bug, so I've filed http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLX-461 to track it.

Comment: Let's focus on `<suffix>${line.separator}</suffix>` for a bit. Are you saying token replacement happens before XML parsing?

Comment: Nope, I'm saying that the mere act of Maven's parsing the `pom.xml` causes leading and trailing whitespace to be trimmed.  You can see this by simply doing `mvn help:effective-pom`. Go ahead and specify a configuration value for any plugin and surround the value with leading and trailing space, then do `mvn help:effective-pom`.  You'll notice the space is destroyed.  Maven property interpolation has nothing to do with this (I discovered).

Comment: You can post the JIRA items you've created as an answer to your own question and accept your own answer as the right answer. That way this question can be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per instructions, I am answering this question by referring people to the following JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5380 (originally at  http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLX-461 ).

Answer (score 5):

The codehaus links don't work anymore, but I found in the maven documentation that since version 3.0.something you can add an attribute xml:space="preserve" to any element you don't want trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$${line.separator}`. The double `$$` escape it. A chap on the Codehaus IRC channel shared his finding recently, so the credit should actually go to him.